# AP stat multiple choice need help

Tags: statistics

AP Statistic

A simple random sample produces a sample mean, x(bar), of 15. A 95 percent confidence interval for the corresponding population mean is 15 +/- 3. Which of the following statements must be true?

(A) Ninety-five percent of the population measurements fall between 12 and 18.

(B) Ninety-Five of the sample measurements fall between 12 and 18.

(C) If 100 samples were taken, 95 of the sample means would fall between 12 and 18.

(D) $P(12\leq x(bar) \leq 18) = 0.95$

(E) If mu = 19, this x(bar) of 15 would be unlikely to occur.

Can you guys help me with this one? I thought the answer was B, but the answer is actually E. I don't get how come B isn't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 95 percent confidence interval for the population mean says that 95 percent of times the interval will "catch" the true population mean (which is not known). 
We have to take numerous samples and 95 % of the times, our confidence interval will contain the true population mean.

A is incorrect as we dont everything about the population.

B is incorrect as there can be samples where all measurements are way off.

C is incorrect as we have to take numerous samples, say in millions.

D is incorrect as Confidence intervals are specified for population means and not sample mean, x(bar).

E is correct as mu is population mean. If it were known to be 19, it is unlikely that x(bar) would be 15. This is the basis of hypothesis testing.

Answer (score -1):

First thing wrong with A has to do with wording. You would say something like I am or We are 95% confident..... Or at the 95% confidence interval.....
B would need to say after taking many samples of size  whatever the confidence interval was calculated using a method that will capture the population parameter in 95% of the samples.